# Cleaning up date data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where the value for date is either looking like "updated 11 April 2022" or "11-Apr-22".
anyway to unify the dates and make them all the exact same format?

I know I can remove the "update" with regex but how do I turn "11 April 2022" to "11-Apr-22" or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) combined with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html?highlight=str%20replace#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
df['col'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['col'].replace(r'updated\s*', '', regex=True))
               .dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
             )
```

For `11 April 2022` use `%d %B %Y` as `strftime` format
output:

```
0    11-Apr-22
1    11-Apr-22
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["updated 11 April 2022", "11-Apr-22"]})
```